# How to replace menu key with capslock and capslock with left control using xkb

Tags: keyboard, xkb, setxkbmap

I followed the instruction [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control/65600#65600) by defining my own xkbsymbols

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "replace_Menu_Capslock" {
replace key <COMP>  { [ Caps_Lock ] };
replace key <CAPS>  { [ Control_L ] };
};
```

The menu key now becomes Caps_Lock, but the `<CAPS>` key (original caps_lock key) is still Caps_Lock. Any thought on why replace works for `<comps>` but not for `<caps>`?
Thank you very much!